# How to add an image to a pdf using Capacitor pdf-generator plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

[image]I’m using capacitor pdf-generator plugin to create a pdf. I managed to do so as long as the html code is limited to non image tag, code in which I inject some dynamic data by nesting variable using `${ }`.

Now, my aim is to bind the src attribute of an ```img`` tag to a variable so that I can change the logo displayed in the created PDF.

Where I fail: what appears on the PDF is a white space with dashed borders (check picture attached). So I guess that the path must be correct because if not it would show the missing icon (issue I went through before I could format correctly the path).

Anyone who already had that trouble?
[image: see top right corner]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the images to base64 here https://www.base64-image.de/

then add the codes directly to your image tag

Answer (score 2):

Finally bypassed this issue by storing the base64 data when selecting a logo and using it directly in the img tag.
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,${base64data} " />`